# .NET ResourceManager - using neutral culture localization file for specific culture

Tags: c#, .net, resourcemanager

Maybe a stupid question, but I wonder what is the ResourceManager strategy of selecting specific localization file and localized strings if only neutral culture localization files (en, de etc.) are available (or a combination of neutral and specific culture), but specific culture (en-GB, de-DE etc.) is selected. Any link to documentation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`ResourceManager` by default will fallback by calling [`CultureInfo.Parent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent?view=net-6.0) (using the [`CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=net-6.0) property if not provided) until a matching resource is found. If no localized resource is found in any of those locations, it will fallback to the culture (and optionally the `UltimateResourceFallbackLocation`) that is set in the [`NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute?view=net-6.0).

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly)]
```

To specify to fallback to the invariant culture, use an empty string.

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly)]
```

To specify that the resource is in a satellite assembly, use `UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.SatelliteAssembly`.

For example you set `de-DE` as the `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

`ResourceManager` will first attempt to find the resource in a `de-DE` localized resource. If it doesn't exist, then it will attempt to use `de`. If the resource is still not found, it will fallback to the culture and assembly in `NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute`.

Reference: https://flylib.com/books/en/3.147.1.43/1/